# SOAP Get Request using POSTMAN

Tags: soap, get, postman

Can any one help me on the below?

1. Is it possible to run SOAP Get Request through POSTMAN?
2. If so, can you please provide some links or steps as i am getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible.
2. How about a link with steps from the postman blog itself? http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/08/22/making-soap-requests-using-postman/

Comment: Thanks for the response. It address my question but output xml in postman looks bad than in SOAPUI

Comment: ><GetCountryByCurrencyCodeResult>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;Name&gt;Afghanistan, Islamic State of&lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;CountryCode&gt;af&lt;/CountryCode&gt;

Comment: How does this answer the question? "Is it possible to run SOAP Get Request through POSTMAN?" The page you link explains how to to a POST, not a GET.

Answer (score 0):

Change the response to xml format to get better structure.
Yes it is possible to run GET request through POSTMAN. For this only the Method should be GET and you should be aware that the wsdl will accept GET method.